# Passing multiple parameter to MVC WebAPi from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

Just started with WebApi and have multiple problems. Read tons of info, but probably missing some concepts.

In my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ChangePassword")]
public string ChangePassword([FromBody]string username, [FromBody] string newpassword, [FromBody]string oldpassword)
{
    return new Models.User() { Username = username, NewPassword = newpassword, OldPassword = oldpassword }.ChangePassword();

}
```

Routing ::

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApiController",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And I am  Calling this Service from JQUERY

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://XXXXX/api/service/cHANGEPASSWORD",
                            async: true,
                            data: source,
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert(result);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                            }
```

Now, I have put a debugger on ChangePassword   Method within  WebAPi ,  and when i runs the code..  it doesnot get hit and also i don't  get any  Error From Error Function in Ajax.

Note  ::  Both HTML Page and WEBAPI  are on same project. So, their is no  cross domain issue  here

Comment: Can you show the 'source' variable's definition/contents?

Comment: Is the below answer working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source variable is not shown, but should be in this format for your changepassword function:

username, [FromBody] string newpassword, [FromBody]string oldpassword

```
var source = { username : $('#username').val(), newpassword : $('#newPassword').val(), oldpassword: $('#oldPassword').val() };

                   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://XXXXX/api/service/ChangePassword",
                    async: true,
                    data: source,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                    }
```

you can change item id's/etc to suit your needs..

Answer (score 0):

Create Reset Password View Model To Post This is secure while transferring data through request

```
 [HttpPost]
[ActionName("ChangePassword")]
public string ChangePassword(RestPasswordViewModel vm)
{
    return new Models.User() { Username = vm.username, NewPassword = vm.newpassword, OldPassword = vm.oldpassword }.ChangePassword();

}





 public class RestPasswordViewModel 
    {
     public string username {get;set;}

     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     public string newpassword{get;set;}

     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     public string oldpassword {get;set;}

    }
```

OR User Get Method

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ChangePassword")]
public string ChangePassword(string username, string newpassword,string oldpassword)
{
    return new Models.User() { Username = username, NewPassword = newpassword, OldPassword = oldpassword }.ChangePassword();

}
```

If this answered your question, Please check right on left side.